# Geometric proof of a result obtained analytically?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

I'm writing a paper at the moment, and I've stumbled across a fact that I need. I can prove it analytically, using inner products, but I especially want a simple Euclidean geometry proof.

The fact is as follows: suppose we have two lines that intersect uniquely at a point $B$, and fix another point $D$ on the plane. Let $G$ and $F$ be the respective points of orthogonal projection, from $B$, onto the two lines. Further, let $K$ and $H$ be points on $DG$  and $DF$ respectively, such that $\vec{DK}$ is the unit vector in the direction of $\vec{DG}$ and $\vec{DH}$ is the unit vector in the direction of $\vec{DF}$.

[image: Diagram]

Then, as I've discovered,
$$\left|\vec{DB}\right| = \frac{2 \cdot \left|\vec{GF}\right|}{\left|\vec{DK} + \vec{DH}\right| \cdot \left|\vec{DK} - \vec{DH}\right|}.$$

I've got a messy, inelegant and uninformative proof using inner products, so I was hoping to find a proof that just uses simple Euclidean geometry.

Anyone have some ideas?

Comment: The picture suggests looking at the semicircle with diameter $DB$ which passes through points $F$ and $G$.  Your posts relates only about $K$ and $H$ that they lie on respective legs of right triangles, so perhaps their exact position is unimportant?

Comment: @hardmath The position of $K$ and $H$ are important, as segments (or vectors) with those two points as end points make up the denominator in the fraction. That denominator, by the way, is the product of the two diagonals in the parallelogram spanned by $\vec{DK}$ and $\vec{DH}$, so it's equal to four times the area of the triangle $DHK$.

Comment: @hardmath That's my main doubt about proving this with Euclidean geometry: it's not a usual thing to insist on unit vectors. But, scaling them to, say, vectors of length $2$ will ruin the result, as the denominator scales by a factor of $4$.

Comment: the angle between unit vectors will be the same as angle between the lines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\angle GDF=\theta$. Then $\displaystyle \left|\overrightarrow{DK}+\overrightarrow{DH}\right|=2\cos\frac{\theta}{2}$ and $\displaystyle \left|\overrightarrow{DK}-\overrightarrow{DH}\right|=2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}$

So, $$\frac{2}{\left|\overrightarrow{DK}+\overrightarrow{DH}\right|\left|\overrightarrow{DK}-\overrightarrow{DH}\right|}=\frac{2}{2\sin\theta}=\frac{1}{\sin\theta}$$

Let $O$ be the midpoint of $BD$. It is the centre of the circle $BDGF$. Let $M$ be the midpoint of $GF$. Then $\displaystyle \angle FOM=\frac{\angle GOF}{2}=\frac{2\angle GDF}{2}=\theta$

So, $\displaystyle \sin\theta=\frac{\left|\overrightarrow{MF}\right|}{\left|\overrightarrow{OF}\right|}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}\left|\overrightarrow{GF}\right|}{\frac{1}{2}\left|\overrightarrow{DB}\right|}=\frac{\left|\overrightarrow{GF}\right|}{\left|\overrightarrow{DB}\right|}$

Therefore, $$\left|\overrightarrow{DB}\right|=\frac{2\left|\overrightarrow{GF}\right|}{\left|\overrightarrow{DK}+\overrightarrow{DH}\right|\left|\overrightarrow{DK}-\overrightarrow{DH}\right|}$$